# I want to create item into SharePoint list through .Net core console or Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, sharepoint-online, csom

I want to create an item into SharePoint online list through the .Net core console or Web API through CSOM, so is it possible? If yes then How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree with @Daboul and maybe what you need is [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

I believe MS Graph API would be the best way to achieve that: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/dotnet-core

With Graph API you can access most of MS services: One Drive, Sharepoint, Teams ...

You can start by checking the Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer I see a Sharepoint List section in there which should suit your need.

.NET Core is a good language to use it.